# Admob pro not working as expected with Cordova

Tags: javascript, cordova, admob, crosswalk-runtime, crosswalk

I'm trying to show some ads with my app but it seems that unless I autoshow and Interstitial ad, it won't work.  It throws no errors, I prepare the ad like i should and use "AdMob.showInterstitial()".  But it does absolutely nothing.

```
AdMob.prepareInterstitial({
adId: admobid.interstitial,
autoShow: false
```

});

And then after that I use this:

```
AdMob.showInterstitial();
```

I have no idea what I am doing wrong. If it makes a difference I am using Crosswalk

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are calling the ad in a method. It doesn't work as shown on the tutorial online.

Comment: Could you show me a simple example of what you mean?

Comment: Can i please get some help on this.